# Access VBA Converting DateTime to Short Date in DCount

Tags: datetime, ms-access, vba

I am using Access 2007.

I need to convert a the value of a field that is full date and time to just the date part, so that I can see if it is a match in a dcount for today's date.  I have tried DateValue(), Int(), etc and I *think* I did them right (there's a possibility I didn't).  It doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code **WITHOUT** any of the things I've tried, so as not to confuse.  You can see here that the `[tsUpdated]` value and the `CurDate` value will not match because `[tsUpdated]` is the full date and `CurDate` is just the date.  How do I get `[tsUpdated]` to be formatted as just the date in the DCount...and have it work?

```
GetID = Forms!frm_MainMenu!AssocIDBox
CurRecord = Forms!frm_EC_All![L#].Value
CurDate = DateValue(Now)
'
Dim tCompleted As String: tComp = DCount("[EC#]", "tbl_Data", "[AssocID] = " & GetID & " AND [tsUpdated] = " & CurDate)
'
MsgBox "You completed " & tComp & " today.", vbOKOnly, "Summary"
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Dim tCompleted As String. Should be dimmed as Long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateValue(Now)` returns the same Date/Time value as does `Date()`.  So instead of `CurDate = DateValue(Now)`, you could do `CurDate = Date`.  However, I don't see any benefit from saving the value in that *CurDate* variable; just use `Date()` when you need it.

A greater concern is *"Converting DateTime to Short Date in DCount"*.  That means the db engine must convert the *tsUpdated* value from every candidate row of *tbl_Data* to determine which rows satisfy your `WHERE` clause criteria.  And that means the engine can not take advantage of an index on *tsUpdated* to quickly identify candidate rows.  So don't do that.

An approach like this could be much faster with *tsUpdated* indexed:

```vb
DCount("[EC#]", "tbl_Data", "[AssocID] = " & GetID & " AND [tsUpdated] >= Date AND [tsUpdated] < (Date + 1)")
```

Comment: Cogent points, thank you.  I understand the logic behind this and when I implemented it, it worked great.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use

```
Format([tsUpdated],"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

and create a query that converts tsUpdated to a ShortDate.
For example:

```
 SELECT 
    [Field1], 
    [Field2],
    Format([tsUpdated],"mm/dd/yyyy") AS tsUpdated_S
 FROM
    tbl_Data
```

Save this and adjust your DCount to use this query instead of the table.